# Using BeautifulSoup get the text from the next span where the previous contained

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting BeautifulSoup to return the text I need.
I've used a Strainer to get the `<div>` I need but I'm having trouble getting the text inside I need.
What would be the best way to get the "value" of the ISCED code given the html structure below. There are other class_="inline..." in the BS object so its not possible just find class_=inline_value and there could be more than 1 ISCED code in the html

```
 <span class="inline_label">
   ISCED:
  </span>
  <span class="inline_value">
   0410: Business &amp; Admin not defined
  </span>
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to do this:

```
In [22]: import re

In [23]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [24]: soup = BeautifulSoup('''<span class="inline_label">
   ....:    ISCED:
   ....:   </span>
   ....:   <span class="inline_value">
   ....:    0410: Business &amp; Admin not defined
   ....:   </span>''', 'lxml')
   ....:   

In [25]: for el in soup(text=re.compile(r'ISCED')):
   ....:     print(el.parent.find_next_sibling().get_text())
   ....:     

   0410: Business & Admin not defined
```

Or

```
In [26]: for el in soup(class_=re.compile(r'inline')):
   ....:     print(el.get_text(strip=True))
   ....:
ISCED:
0410: Business & Admin not defined
```